# Backslash URL of REST API Call Made with Invoke-RestMethod Generates Error

Tags: rest, powershell

I've got a snippet of code like the following:

```
$url = 'https://foo/accounts/thing%5CBSTNTZ-MTRFKR'
$request_content_type = 'application/xml'

$response_checkout = Invoke-RestMethod `
-Credential $credential `
-Method Get `
-Uri $url `
-ContentType $request_content_type
```

The `Invoke-RestMethod` generates the following exception:

```
PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          : System.Net.HttpWebRequest
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
ErrorDetails          : Account not found: ?\thing
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

The backslash in the account name (thing\BSTNTZ-MTRFKR) seems to be the culprit. I am encoding the backslash with %5c using `[System.Uri]::EscapeUriString()`. Is there some other trick to adding a blackslash to the URI?

The following link will take you to the API reference for the API I'm calling.

https://docops.ca.com/ca-privileged-identity-management/12-8/en/integrating/rest-based-api/checkout-an-account

Comment: `Account not found: ?\thing`

Comment: Maybe the service is stripping off any non-alphabetic character through the end of the 'account'. ("billy", "suzie", etc work)

Comment: It's the backslash that's causing the issue. Not sure what to do about it.

Comment: Does the service support including the domain?  Usually, these things work like `accounts?username=mtrfkr+domain=thing` etc

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, your suggestion makes sense, but no, at least based on the API's documentation. The URI needs to be in the form: `https://<host_name>:18443/iam/api/1.0/restapi/environments/ac/endpoints/<endpoint_name>/accounts/<account_name>`. The account name can be any string. In this case, it just happens to have a backslash in it.

Comment: Is this a public API?  What service are you looking at?

Comment: It’s a service for this POS app named ControlMinder (Identity Manager) written by CA. API isn’t public.